# Explanation of "must needs"

Tags: adverbs

Recently I ran across the sentence:

> "Just why the law prescribed thirty-nine lashes instead of forty or forty-one and so on, *must needs* remain unanswered."

How did a plural verb like "needs" wind up as an adverb?  Is it alone in this phenomenon, or are there other examples that appear to be an odd misplacement of a second verb, but are actually adverbs as well?

Comment: Answers have quite thoroughly addressed the actual question, but just to make it clear: ‘needs’ (in its verbal form) is specifically _not_ plural, but singular.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

*Needs* is an old-fashioned or even archaic adverb in modern English. It comes from the noun **need** and the Germanic masculine/neuter genitive ending **-s**, which at some point in time came to be used in older English and other Germanic languages to form adverbs. From the *Oxford English Dictionary*:

> In *once, twice, thrice, hence, since,* etc., the suffix is written differently. In *against, alongst, amongst, amidst,* and the dialectal *onst* (see *once*), the original *-es, -s* has become -*st*.

This suffix is still frequent and semi-productive with other stems in Dutch: *onverwachts* "unexpectedly", *daags na* "a day after", etc. I believe German has similar examples. English *always, sideways* etc. contain the same suffix.

In Old English or earlier, before the emergence of the adverbial suffix *-s*, there existed several masculine and neuter words in the genitive case—which ended on *-(e)s*—that were used adverbially: *dæges* "by day", *nédes* "needs", *þances* "voluntarily". By analogy, this masculine/neuter genitive ending was extended to make adverbs out of feminine nouns as well, as in *nihtes* "by night". From there it became a general adverbial suffix. (Examples were taken from the OED.)

Comment: Very interesting,"Cerberus, proficiat! Contemporary German still has "nachts" for "by night", even though "Nacht" is feminine.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: Ah, that's what I thought (I was too lazy to look it up; Dutch has *'s nachts*, where *'s* is short for *des*, oddly enough; but Dutch is notoriously sloppy with sexes).

Comment: Do please note that [*needs must* alternates with *must needs*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=needs+must%2Cmust+needs&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=5&smoothing=5&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cneeds%20must%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmust%20needs%3B%2Cc0), and that these days they are about equally seen — or unseen, as the case may be.

Comment: @tchrist: Noted! I believe I use either order myself.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not so sure it "wound up" an adverb/adjective. Chaucer wrote *A man must needs love [mauger](http://www.wordnik.com/words/mauger) his head* (where I'm guessing *mauger* relates to French *malgré* = *in spite of*)

Thanks to @pavium for [this link](http://www.randomhouse.com/wotd/index.pperl?date=20010817) - which deserves more upvotes than my answer!

The usage is generally archaic/formal/academic. It probably survives partly because it echoes the equally archaic [needs must](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/needs-must.html) [when the Devil drives].

It's not a "plural verb" (nor "second person singular verb", nor "plural noun"). I think it's always been an adverb meaning "necessarily". I'm not aware of any other words that happen to be both noun and verb *and* have an [archaic] adverbial form that's the same apart from ending is 's', but even if there were, I doubt you could call it a meaningfully productive 'pattern'.

Semantically, *needs* functions as an [intensifier](http://free-english-study.com/grammar/intensifiers.html) to the preceding *must*. It doesn't really need to be present - it's just adding emphasis, with perhaps a touch of [gravitas](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/gravitas) from the archaic overtones.

Answer (score 5):

This question was discussed here:

> http://www.randomhouse.com/wotd/index.pperl?date=20010817

While the  reference classifies *needs* as an adverb, I think it owes more to [the imagined requirements of] conjugation than number for the 's' at the end. (as in 'I *need*', 'He *needs*', etc)

It's more likely a writer affecting a older style of writing, in line with the subject of corporal punishment.

Comment: Your conjecture about conjugation is surely shot down by the fact that *We needs must...* is just as acceptable as *He needs must...*

Comment: I already added the word 'imagined' to point out that what the OP thought was plural might be explained another way. Perhaps simply reproduction of earlier usage. I can't argue with the learned explanations in other answers, but I might leave my answer, if only because of the 'randomhouse' link.

Comment: It is an excellent link, I agree. I was only disputing the *conjugation* bit. I also agree with your last sentence, which is echoed by my last. But cutting to the chase - can I pinch your link if I give credit? :)

Comment: By all means, FF.

Comment: One need not and indeed must not use *need* as an inflected verb when its modal use is required.

Answer (score 4):

It may be helpful to read the phrase *must needs* as *must, of necessity*.

Why does this make sense? As mentioned by others here, the -s on *needs* is an artifact from the Germanic genitive suffix -es, used most often to show possession. In modern German, the genitive case can usually be translated to English using the preposition *of*.

For instance, in *das Kleid meiner Schwester*, the suffix -er has been added in place of a preposition in order to make clear the owner of the dress (*meiner* is genitive, cp. the alternative dative *von meiner*). In English, the phrase could read *my sister's dress*, or, more aptly, *the dress of my sister*. The analogy to "must needs" and "must, of necessity" is immediate.

Answer (score 0):

It is used by Tyrion Lannister in the first Game of Thrones book. Here it is simply intended to be a synonym for "has to". However the structure is abandoned by George RR Martin in subsequent books.

Comment: Except for in "A Dance with Dragons", the fifth book, where it is extremely over-used.

Answer (score 0):

"Must needs" occurs a number of times in Shakespeare.  I used to think it was Shakespeare twisting words around for effect.  Now I see he's using a common phrase of his day for emphasis and rhythm.

For example, Puck in Midsummer Nights Dream:    III,2

"Then will two at once woo one; 
That must needs be sport alone;"

Answer (score 0):

"Must needs" is an archaic phrase used as an adverb, meaning 'must necessarily". It is similar to "have to" or "has to" :
He must needs do it. = He has to do it.

Comment: This could do with a supporting reference for "must needs".